# How do you add elements and access values dynamically in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working on a small project that allows the user to add dynamic fields. On clicking a button I have been able to create input fields dynamically. I am trying to access the value of each field and push it to the service. On the other hand, another component should make the number of div depending upon the number of input fields created by the user and each div should contain a title depending upon the user input in the input field.

**register.component.html**

```
<h2>Demo App</h2>
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
    <button (click)="addRooms()">Add Room </button>
  <div formArrayName="addRoom">
    <div *ngFor="let r of Rooms.controls; let i=index" [formGroupName]="i">
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter A Room Name" formControlName="roomName" (keyup)="abc()"/>

      </mat-form-field>
      <button (click)="deleteRoom(i)">Delete</button>
    </div>


  </div>
  <input type="button" (click)="getRoomValues()" value="Get">
</form>
```

**register.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { RegisterModel } from '../models/register.model';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  myForm: FormGroup;
  room: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder, private r:Router, private _ele:ElementRef, private _render: Renderer) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      addRoom: this.formBuilder.array([]),
      tst: new FormControl()
    });

  }

  getVal(){
    console.log(this.myForm.value.tst);
  }

  get Rooms(){
    return this.myForm.get('addRoom') as FormArray;
  }


  addRooms(){
    this.room = this.formBuilder.group({
      roomName:new FormControl()
    })

    this.Rooms.push(this.room);
    console.log(this.Rooms);
  }
  abc(){
    console.log(this.room.value.roomName);
  }

  deleteRoom(i){
    this.Rooms.removeAt(i);
  }

  get roomNames(){
    return this.myForm.get('roomNames') as FormArray;
  }
  getRoomValues(){
    console.log(this.myForm.value.addRoom)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code sample for couple of fields with dynamic Add & Remove functionality.

```
                              <form [formGroup]="linksForm" class="form-horizontal">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Links
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
                                            <div formArrayName="links" *ngFor="let item of linksForm.get('links').controls; let i = index;">
                                                <div [formGroupName]="i">
                                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                                        <input class="form-control col-md-5" formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-5">
                                                        <input type="url" pattern="https?://.+" placeholder="http://example.com" class="form-control col-md-5"
                                                         formControlName="link">
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="col-md-2">
                                                        <button class="btn btn-warning btn-xs m-t-sm" type="button" (click)="removeItem(i)">
                                                            <i name="save" class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                        <button *ngIf="i == linksForm.get('links').controls.length - 1" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs m-t-sm" type="button" (click)="addItem()">
                                                            <i name="save" class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

TS : Declare below variables in class :

```
linksForm: FormGroup;
links: FormArray;
```

Inside ngOnInit() initialize form with at least one row :

```
this.linksForm = new FormGroup({
            'links': new FormArray([this.createItem()])
        });
```

Add below functions for Add / Remove :

```
addItem(): void {
    this.links = this.linksForm.get('links') as FormArray;
    this.links.push(this.createItem());
  }

   removeItem(index: any) {
      this.links.removeAt(index);

      if (this.links.length == 0) {
         this.addItem();
      }
   }

createItem(): FormGroup {
        return new FormGroup({
            id: new FormControl(),
            name: new FormControl(),
            link: new FormControl(),
            createdAt: new FormControl()
        });
    }
```

Comment: what is createItem() in this code? The console says "this.createItem is not a function"

Comment: Adding and removing elements works fine!! But how do I get the values of the field?

Comment: You can just do this.linksForm.value and it will return JSON of form values which you have fields with all added members.

Comment: I am able to create multiple input fields dynamically. Each element holds a property in the value attribute under FormArray. When i try to retrieve the value of all the fields. I get the value of only the last field. How can i get all of them? Refer to the video, I have tried to highlight the current status of the program and the need as well. https://youtu.be/eF3UIKfaAH4

Comment: The get button calls a function named abc which has one statement "console.log(this.room.value.roomName);" What should be the statement to access all the input field values

Comment: In your case "this.myForm.get('addRoom').value;" should return array of all rooms added.